# Method modifiers and glob assignments

Tags: perl, moose

Sometimes Moose's method modifiers do not play well with symbol table entries created by other packages that try to do Moose-like things their own way.

I am working with some older code that follows this pattern:

```
package MethodCreator;

sub make_some_method {
    my $caller = caller();
    *{$caller . '::generated_method'} = sub { print 'I am a generated method' }
}

1;
```

The intent of the MethodCreator package is to add some standard definitions to multiple consumer packages, and it implements this via direct glob assignment.  The problem is, these created methods do not play well with Moose's method modifiers:

```
package Consumer;

use Moose;
use MethodCreator;

MethodCreator::make_some_method();

# The following line causes compilation to fail                                                                                                                                                              
# before generated_method => sub { print 'About to call a generated method: ' };                                                                                                                             

generated_method();

1;
```

As the comment indicates, an attempt to use a method modifier on one of these dynamically-added subroutines results in a compile time error ("generated_method is not in the inheritance hierarchy").

It will not be practical to change or replace MethodCreator (as much as that may be the "right solution").  So the question is: how can package Consumer be changed to make the 'before' modifier play well with such subroutines, i.e. to behave as you would expect if 'generated_method' were defined directly within Consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Class::Method::Modifiers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers) to do that instead of using the built-in Moose modifiers. Make sure you do not import anything from them, though, or you will get *redefined* warnings. Instead, call `before` explicitly from the Class::Method::Modifiers package.

```
package MethodCreator;
use strict;
use warnings;
no strict 'refs';

sub make_some_method {
    my $caller = caller();
    *{$caller . '::generated_method'} = sub { print 'I am a generated method' }
}

package Consumer;

use Moose;
use Class::Method::Modifiers ();

MethodCreator::make_some_method();

# This one works
Class::Method::Modifiers::before( generated_method => sub { print 'About to call a generated method: ' });

generated_method();

1;
```

Output:

```
About to call a generated method: I am a generated method
```

## Now why does this work?

[The C::M::M docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers#NOTES) say this:

> Note that the syntax and semantics for these modifiers is directly borrowed from Moose (the implementations, however, are not).

Simplified, this overwrites the sub in the package with its own sub, which does your stuff and calls the original one afterwards.

In Moose on the other hand those are implemented in Class::MOP::Method::Wrapped, and they use the MOP to handle all the fancy inheritance stuff as well as multiple modifiers. But because you don't have those with your 'manually generated' subroutine/method, they will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The package in which a sub is compiled is associated with the sub.

```
$ perl -e'
   package Abc;
   use Devel::Peek;
   Dump(sub { });
'
SV = IV(0xf54988) at 0xf54998
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0xf54a88
  SV = PVCV(0xf70aa8) at 0xf54a88
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (PADMY,ANON,WEAKOUTSIDE,CVGV_RC)
    COMP_STASH = 0xf72818       "Abc"
    START = 0xf7a5d0 ===> 0
    ROOT = 0xf7a6e0
    GVGV::GV = 0xf80b68 "Abc" :: "__ANON__"       <-----
    FILE = "-e"
    DEPTH = 0
    FLAGS = 0x490
    OUTSIDE_SEQ = 94
    PADLIST = 0xf72830
    PADNAME = 0xf72848(0xf7ab90) PAD = 0xf72998(0xfacb90)
    OUTSIDE = 0xf54bd8 (MAIN)
```

Apparently, Moose's `before` checks this. You can't change this, so you will have to change `make_some_method` as follows if you want to keep using Moose's `before`.

```
sub _install_method {
    my ($pkg_name, $sub_name, $sub) = @_;
    eval("
       package $pkg_name;
       sub $sub_name { &\$sub }
       return 1;
    ")
       or die($@);
}

sub make_some_method {
   _install_method(
      scalar(caller()),
      generated_method => sub {
         print 'I am a generated method';
      },
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you assume `$caller` is a Moose class?[1]  If so, you can do the method creation the Moose way, with

```
$caller->meta->add_method(generated_method => sub {
    print "I am a generated method\n";
});
```

If the code doing the generation can depend on Moose, but the calling code may or may not be a Moose class, you can say

```
Class::MOP::Class->initialize($caller)->add_method(generated_method => sub {
    print "I am a generated method\n";
});
```

and that will work with any kind of Perl class.

[1] Or a Moo class.  But not a Moose or Moo class that inherits from a non-Moose non-Moo class!